# Setting HTTPS Proxy in Winbox for MikroTik

Tags: proxy, router, https, mikrotik

I am using **MikroTik** router model **RB750**, I need to use **HTTPS proxy** method for some of my clients. 
The Proxy Server (VPS) is in another country and i have the IP address and the Port Number and a username and password for connection, in the Proxy Server i have a **CCPROXY** program.
i have a VPN in router but i need th set HTTPS proxy in the same way to enable it for some client and disable it for some.

Can anyone tell me how to do it in **Winbox** software do?

Comment: I don't cllearly understand. You need to redicect some users to remote Proxy? It can be done, but remote proxy must support transparent proxying of https (use dynamic fake certificates).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Mikrotik RouterOS does not support acting as HTTPS proxy. Also if you check further it does not have any options for SSL certificates regarding to its proxy.

You can use Linux/squid or Microsoft ISA / TMG for HTTPS scenario.

If you want, Mikrotik has HTTP proxy with authentication in IP > Web Proxy.